# Who were the people working for Enoch in S5E1?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

At the beginning of season 5 in *Agents of SHIELD*, Coulson's team is (mostly) abducted from Rae's Diner by Enoch and a crew of men. These men all seem to be human. One of them even says:

> My wife thinks that I'm at a friend's house for our fantasy draft. Doesn't even occur to her that we're in the middle of the season. Doesn't even occur to her.

They are also wearing standard-looking military gear for humans. Together these hint to me that they are human.

What is really strange is that Enoch claims frequently that he isn't supposed to interfere unless there are dire situations (extinction-level events). So how does he have a team or humans already picked out that has done this before (the man asks another man if he has done one of these recently and mentions that he hasn't) and has all of their gear? They are also the ones that hand him the device to freeze Coulson's team.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### They were possibly private military contractors and not S.H.I.E.L.D agents

---

In *Season 4: Episode 22* "*World's End*", after everything that happened with Aida and the Framework, Fitz decided to turn himself in as Mack tells everyone that the authorities were coming for them.

> **Mack**: We picked up radio chatter on the Zephyr. The good news is, is that Talbot is alive. He's in a coma, but alive. *The bad news is they know we're here, - and they're on their way.*
>
> **Fitz**: Yeah, you should go while you can.
>
> **Daisy**: Yeah, we're all going.
>
> **Fitz**: No, I'm gonna stay. This is my fault Aida, the LMDs, all the deaths. Those aren't on S.H.I.E.L.D. Those are on me. And, uh, I can explain that I built the LMD that shot Talbot.

So Enoch could have disguised himself as the agent in-charge of capturing Fitz and others thereby gaining access to Coulson and team for *the mission*.

But a few things contradict this. Firstly, listen to the conversation between the two soldiers outside. One of them actually says

> **Soldier**: Haven't done one of these in a while.
>   You? My wife thinks that I'm at a friend's house for our fantasy draft.
>   Doesn't even occur to her that we're in the middle of the season.
>   Doesn't even occur her.

Their formations and techniques show some sort of trained military sense in them. But this conversation tells that their families don't know what they *actually* do.

Secondly,

> **Soldier**: We left one sitting at the counter, sir.
>
> **Enoch**: Yeah. Not on the list.

If they were actual agents, they would have taken all of them specifically Fitz as he was the prime target; however he's the only one they leave behind. Since Enoch tells *he's not on the list*.

Thirdly, in the beginning, we see Enoch renting into a shady van with fake logo on it. As far as we have seen across the series (and also the MCU movies where S.H.I.E.L.D was involved), S.H.I.E.L.D uses its own transport at all times.

So, it looks like Enoch hired some contractors to capture Coulson and the team for his mission.

**PS**: It has been established that such contractors already exist in MCU. Billy Russo, for example, in the Netflix series *Punisher*, owns such a company called ANVIL that has ex-military personnel who can be hired for various *jobs*.

Comment: That van was unlikely SHIELD since it changed its logo as it was being driven and Fitz was surprised at this. But overall I like this. The private contractors could likely be hired for lots of grab and go jobs.

Comment: @thaimin yes. And since Enoch has been observing human activities since a long time, its likely he knew about such secret organizations.

Answer (score -1):

Well, first off, **SPOILERS!!!**, but all is revealed later in season 5 anyway.

Enoch is an alien called a "Chronicom", as are his team (I believe - and we come across other Chronicoms later, both friendly and not). They keep an eye on Earth and, yes, can interfere in order to prevent an extinction-level event, because that event also disrupts the wider galaxy in the future.

In this case, they abduct most of the team and send them to the future, so that they can work to prevent the event in the past. It is revealed that they are not in anyone's employ, but following a prophecy.

Comment: I know this but it doesn’t explain how he has a team of humans with history. We never see him working with other humans until after he became aware of the prophecy.

Comment: And even after that point very carefully working with them.

Comment: No, it doesn't. I'm still not sure if Enoch's team WERE other Chronicons or not, but either way we have to imagine that Enoch will have arrived on Earth with various resources that he could have paid his way with. Whether they are human or not doesn't really matter as the team has sophisticated technology and Enoch has a great big house with a swimming pool, which he will have paid for somehow. This how isn't explained, but left to the viewer's imagination.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Then to be honest, the question can't be answered sufficiently since it's never fully revealed (to the best of my knowledge). Any answer, to be honest, is speculation.

Comment: @user25730 I agree